# Query nested jsonb using postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I have a nested jsonb column and I'm trying to query a field in the jsonb that is LIKE a value or is that exact value using Postgres9.6

Table: test

Jsonb column: data

```
{
"subject":[
{
          "test1": "blue",
          "test2": "12",
          "test3": "green"
          },
          {
          "test1": "red",
          "test2": "1234",
          "test3": "green"
          }
]}
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT * from test where data ->'subject'->>'test2' like '%12%';
```

Also tried a query for containment:

```
SELECT '{"test":{test1: "blue"}}' :: jsonb@> '{"test":{}}'::jsonb
```

Lastly, tried to access the jsonb elements but get a column "1234" does not exist error.

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM jsonb_array_elements(test.data -> 'subject') as s
    WHERE (s->'test2'= "1234"));
```

The first runs, but I get no data back.

**Function that errors**

```
CREATE FUNCTION search_data (search text)
  RETURNS setof test AS $$
SELECT *
FROM test t, jsonb_array_elements(t.data->'subject') e
WHERE e.value->>'test2' like '%search%';
$$ language sql stable;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect you want something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM test t, jsonb_array_elements(t.data->'subject') e
WHERE e.value->>'test2' like '%12%';
```

Actually, I just noticed that you almost had it working with your last query, but there are a couple of minor syntax & logic errors:

1. you need single quotes not double quotes around the `'1234'` string
   literal (which is why you are getting the "no such column" error),
   and:
2. you need to use `->>` rather than `->` to extract the `data->'test2'`, so it is extracted as `varchar` not as `jsonb`. Otherwise the value gets wrapped in double quotes later in the query evaluation when the `jsonb` is implicitly converted to `varchar` to compare it with the `'1234'::varchar`

The query below works for me:

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM jsonb_array_elements(test.data->'subject') as s
    WHERE (s->>'test2' = '1234'));
```

*See my [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2162a649e56ce6fba78927a7010fc0a6)*